# Align paragraphs to left and right, and center image on footer

Tags: css, css-float, text-align

I need to display one paragraph aligned to the left, another paragraph aligned to the right, and a centered image, all on the same line on the footer of a webpage.

How do I achieve that? My current code gets the second paragraph on a new line.

#### HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <p class="alignleft">Text</p>
    <img id="logo" src="#">
    <p class="alignright">More text</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using "display:inline-block;" on the image?

Comment: @Jnatalzia yes, if I do that the text aligns fine, but the image stays on the left instead of centered.

Comment: Old timey typesetting machines had a `fill` command that would insert a space or leading that automatically took up all the unused space on the line. I have never figured out how to do it so it seemed to work as well in css. Probably should do some reading.

Comment: How tall is the image? Taller than the text? Could the image be centered on another line with line spacing cut down really small?

Comment: Can you re-order the HTML so that the image comes last out of the three inner elements?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps for you:

```html
<div id="footer">
    <span>Text</span>
    <span><img src="http://www.klm.com/jobs/nl/images/icon_flight_32x32_tcm701-312701.gif" /></span>
    <span>More text</span>
</div>
```

```css
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background: gray;
}
#footer span {
    display: table-cell;
}
#footer span:nth-child(2) { text-align: center; }
#footer span:last-child { text-align: right; }
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/TXz6T/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange your HTML:

```html
<div id="footer">
    <p class="alignleft">Text</p>
    <p class="alignright">More text</p>
    <img id="logo" src="#" />
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/hMN8f/)

Comment: It works either way. Even with big fonts. If you wanted the text baseline to align with the picture bottom, it would get tricky but could be done. Try ctrl-middle-mouse-wheel on it and notice how they don't expand in tandem -- at least in Chrome. Its a nice look though.

Comment: That would be very easy `position: absolute` DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/hMN8f/2/

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing:

- Enclosing the texts and images on DIVs,
- Explicitly setting the width percentage of these DIVs to 33.333% (1/3rd) each,
- Left-Floating these DIVs,
- Using text-align to align the elements *inside* those DIVs.

No need to change the order of my HTML, and works with as many elements as needed, just changing the percentage value! :)

### Code

#### HTML

```
<footer>
    <div id="footerleft"><p>Text</p></div>
    <div id="footercenter"><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo"></div> 
    <div id="footerright"><p>More Text</p></div>
</footer>
```

#### CSS

```
#footerleft {
    float: left;
    width:33.333%;
    text-align:left;
}

#footercenter {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
    text-align: center;
}

#footerright {
    float: left;
    width:33.333%;
    text-align:right;
}
```